# What platforms and practices for drawing a web based interactive graph are there?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graph, webgl

I want to dynamically render a web-based graph to the user such that the user may zoom-in/out, focus on a specific node, choose to display it by different orders (depending on the nodes' attributes etc.

The graph will start with very few nodes but is going to grow fastly as user may add new nodes and edges to it.
Also, please suggest also which database technology is best for your solution to store the nodes,edges and their attributes.

So far I've only encountered http://sigmajs.org/

Let me know if more details are required for you to answer.

Comment: Try http://d3js.org for data visualizations.

Comment: wholeheartedly d3.js

Comment: While it's "against the SO rules" to ask for and recommend libraries, I would ditto the previous comments. Use `d3` and don't look back. IMHO, it's the best open source data visualization tool on the web. The database technology is largely irrelevant since most of the common DB's today will efficiently pump data through the web to your browser.